# How to send a byte as mutiple input to a file in Ubuntu

Tags: python, c, input, pipe

I have a `file.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
        char a,b;
        printf("Input your character: \n");
        scanf("%c",&a);
        printf("Input your second character: \n");
        scanf("%c",&b);
        printf("You char: %c %c\n",a,b);
}
```

I use a pipeline to send the first byte 0x01:

```
python -c "print '\x31'" | ./file
```

But it can only send one time, 
I want send: first byte is 0x31 and second byte 0x32, so that the program will print Your char: 1 and 2. How to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple print statements in the python command:

```
python -c 'print "\x31"; print "\x32"' | ./file
```

Or a single print statement, using a newline:

```
python -c 'print "\x31\n\x32"' | ./file
```

Or multiple python commands grouped together before the pipe:

```
(python -c 'print "\x31"'; python -c 'print "\x31"') | ./file
```

It seems the characters must not be separated by a newline, in which case:

```
python -c 'print "\x31\x32"' | ./file
```

Comment: It just print You char: 1, I want print You char: 1 2

Comment: @QChíNguyễn then it's something wrong with your code. Code debugging questions should be asked on [so].

Comment: @QChíNguyễn on second thought, try `python -c 'print "\x31\x32"' | ./file`